# Mediaqueries wont work? Responsive web

Tags: css, media, viewport

I'm currently trying to create a website with different media queries for different device sizes, the problem is, when I add a media query in the media-queries.css file for a different viewport the browser only reads one.

I recently added a media query for a maximum width of 1500 pixels, but now the media query for max-980px wont work.

Here's the css, anyone that can help me?

```
/************************************************************************************
smaller than 980
*************************************************************************************/

@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {

    .slider-container {
        width:                              100%;
        height:                             100px;
        background-color:                   white;
        overflow:                           hidden;
        -moz-border-radius:                 20px;
        border-radius:                      20px;
    }

    .wrapper .slider-container #slideshow { 
        position:                           relative; 
        width:                              100%;
        height:                             300px;
    }

    .wrapper .slider-container #slideshow > div { 
        position:                           absolute; 
    }

    .wrapper .slider-container #slideshow > div img { 
        border:                             20px solid #00e800;
        height:                             100%;
    }

}

/************************************************************************************
smaller than 1500
*************************************************************************************/

@media screen and (max-width: 1500px) {

    .slider-container {
        width:                              100%;
        height:                             400px;
        background-color:                   white;
        overflow:                           hidden;
        -moz-border-radius:                 20px;
        border-radius:                      20px;
    }

    .wrapper .slider-container #slideshow { 
        position:                           relative; 
        width:                              100%;
        height:                             400px;
    }

    .wrapper .slider-container #slideshow > div { 
        position:                           absolute; 
    }

    .wrapper .slider-container #slideshow > div img { 
        border:                             15px solid #f3f70a;
        height:                             100%;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `min-width` component to the larger max-width:

```
@media screen and (min-width:981px) and (max-width: 1500px) {
```

This should tell the system to segregate the two choices, as < 980 will also always be < 1500.

Comment: Ooh thank you very much, how silly of me! I will accept the answer in about 10 min, i'm not able to wright now.

Comment: no problem. and as a heads up, i always find using `min-width` far better than `max-width` for media queries. with `min-width`, they actually build on top of one another, so you don't need to write out the full CSS twice (stuff like `position`, `display`, etc), just the new values for the larger screen.